# Greedy Algorithm implemented in fractional knapsack

Tags: c++, greedy

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
double fractional_knapsack(vector<int>& val,vector<int>& wt,int    weight)//vectors of values and their respective weights and max weight are   passed as parameter
{
int sz=val.size();
vector<double> ratio(sz); //vector to store ratio of values and weights
for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
    ratio[i]=double(val[i]/wt[i]);
}
sort(ratio.begin(),ratio.end(),greater());
//reverse(ratio.begin(),ratio.end());
double max=0.0;
int j=0;
while(max<=weight&&j<sz){
        double(weight[j]);
    max=max+(ratio[j]*weight[j]);
}
return max;
}
int main()
{  int max_weight,n;
cin>>n>>max_weight;
vector<int>values;
vector<int>weights;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>values[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>weights[i];
}
double result=fractional_knapsack(values,weights,max_weight);
cout<<"done/n";
cout<<result;
return 0;
}
```

D:\COdeBlock Projects\Fractional Knapsack\main.cpp|12|error: missing template arguments before '(' token|

it is compiling in devcpp but program_name.exe is crashing

in the method `fractional_knapsack(vector<int>& val,vector<int>& wt,int weight)` why we pass vector as refrence.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, in a debugger, to figure out the source of the crash?

Comment: I don't know how to do that ,please tell me.

Comment: `sort(ratio.begin(),ratio.end(), std::greater<double>());`, and don't use a variable length array because it's non-standard (`double weight[j]`)

Comment: Actually the more I look at it, the less `double(weight[j]);
    max=max+(ratio[j]*weight[j]);` makes any sense

Comment: @abhi11095 Do a query in your favorite search engine. You will find loads of tutorials. This should get you started: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: It may not be clear from the post, but the program doesn't compile. Not sure how OP got an executable at all, perhaps it's from an earlier successful compilation that includes other bugs.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I agree with that.

Comment: @Andy G It worked but exe file is crashing

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Thanks man

Comment: `ratio[i]=double(val[i]/wt[i])` probably won't do what you expected

Comment: @AndyG Well.. I didn't try to compile it. I saw the question is about unexpected behavior - and immediately suggested using the debugger to resolve such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the error message reveal the problem lies with the line 
`sort(ratio.begin(),ratio.end(),greater());`

My guess is that you want 
`sort(ratio.begin(),ratio.end(),greater<double>());`

The sort method expects a comparator. If you look at the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/) for greater, there's an example on how to use it.

Comment: D:\COdeBlock Projects\Fractional Knapsack\main.cpp|12|error: missing template arguments before ')' token| now this

Answer (score 0):

I got the right code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
double fractional_knapsack(vector<int>& val,vector<int>& wt,int   weight)//vectors of values and their respective weights and max weight are passed as parameter
{
int sz=val.size();

vector<double> ratio(sz); //vector to store ratio of values and weights

for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
    ratio[i]=(val[i]/wt[i]);
}
for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
for(int j=i+1;j<sz;j++){
    if(ratio[i]<ratio[j]){
        int temp;
        temp=ratio[i];
        ratio[i]=ratio[j];
        ratio[j]=temp;

        temp=val[i];
        val[i]=val[j];
        val[j]=temp;

        temp=wt[i];
        wt[i]=wt[j];
        wt[j]=temp;
    }
 }
}

//sort(ratio.begin(),ratio.end(),greater<double>());
// sort(val.begin(),val.end(),greater<int>());
//sort(wt.begin(),wt.end(),greater<int>());
//reverse(ratio.begin(),ratio.end());

double max=0.0;
int j=0;

int quantity_left =weight;
while(wt[j]<=quantity_left&&j<sz){
        //double(wt[j]);

    max=max+(ratio[j]*wt[j]);
    cout<<max<<" ";
    quantity_left=quantity_left-wt[j];
    j++;

}
if(wt[j]>quantity_left&&j<sz){
    max=max+(ratio[j]*quantity_left);
   // cout<<max<<" ";
}

return max;
}
int main()
{  int max_weight,n;
cin>>n>>max_weight;
vector<int>values(n);
vector<int>weights(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>values[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>weights[i];
}
double result=fractional_knapsack(values,weights,max_weight);

cout<<result;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to indent first. Your mess is making people's eyes painful